# Calculate a date 12 months ago from a specific date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate a date 12 months ago from specific input date.

Example:

In the Cell `A5` the user input a date **(dd/mm/yyyy)**, and in the Cell `A7` i have the following formula:

```
=MONTH(A5)-12
```

But this formula doesn't work, and i don´t know how to get the date 12 months ago. Any question post on comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926), the best way to do this is with the [`EDATE` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EDATE-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5).

```
=EDATE(A5, -12)
```

(Then format the cell as a Date)

Note that there are some differences between this approach and the one [Scott recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396535/calculate-a-date-12-months-ago-from-a-specific-date/39396566#39396566).  In particular, consider that if your original value is a leap day (February 29th), then subtracting 12 months will fall into a year where there is no leap day.  Scott's approach will return March 1st, where the `EDATE` function will land on February 28th.

The same thing can be seen when adding/subtracting any arbitrary number of months near the end of a long month.  For example, adding one month to March 31st should give April 30th with the `EDATE` approach, but will give May 1st when adding values to date parts.

Comment: And it's shorter.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is better way to get the date i wanted.

Comment: Just for interest, the VBA DATEADD function also gives Feb 28th for Matt's example, so it's consistent. Unfortunately it's not available as a worksheet function.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A5),MONTH(A5)-12,DAY(A5))
```

Or since 12 months is one year:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A5)-1,MONTH(A5),DAY(A5))
```

Comment: I wish they had `DateDiff` for native Excel too.

Comment: @Kyle they do it is a hidden function, but the OP is not trying to find the difference but the actual date. See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: @ScottCraner obviously! I meant `DateAdd` actually, but interesting to know excel has hidden functions.